# How do I write a script for a IF/OR statement for multiple instances?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a script rule that's like the following:

```
if (Field(A) == "Yes" || Field(B) == "Yes" || Field(C) == "Yes")

    return "TITLE"

else

    return ""
```

I have it functioning if I'm only doing "if A OR B", but does not work if I add another field into the mix.

What I'm trying to accomplish is offering a list of items that a user has to choose "yes" or "no" for. If ANY of the three is a "yes", I need the title to show up. So if NONE of them is a "yes", then the title will not show up.

Any suggestions? I've searched around multiple sites and cannot find anything that works.

Comment: Why does it not work? What does it do? What you displayed should work.

Comment: what values are you getting for all three fields when you debug?

Comment: [That works](http://jsfiddle.net/o6mv7mk6/), the problem is somewhere else, please provide an example that can reproduce your problem. You can use a stack snippet to do so.

Comment: probably something other than the if statement you present, try a debugger, or F12 in your browser...

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback!! Confirming the code is correct is super helpful! As Spencer said, it confirms my issue must be because of something else, and now I can look at other possible causes. As of now, I think it's most likely due to the program/purpose i'm using it for. I'm having to write scripts to control output of content on sales flyer templates, that a user will fill out and order online. The template program is suppose to support all javascript (since I do have others incorporated in there), but in this case i'm wondering if it's not accepting it the way it is. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code should work, so if a given field is not working, then the value for that field is probably not what you're expecting it to be. I suggest using `console.log(myFirstVar, mySecondVar, myThirdVar)` immediately before the `if` statement to see what your values are before they hit the `if`.

Also, it's good practice to use `===` instead of `==`. They usually resolve in the same way but `==` will return a match in many cases that `===` does not. Specifically `==` treats all truthy and falsey values as equal, such that if you're doing an `if (myVar == false)` check, you'll get `true` if `myVar` is `0`, `false`, `undefined`, etc.

Comment: Ok, i will also try that and see if it resolves my issue. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code just work fine you can Play with the following **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mjr4ytyp/)** to see that what are you doing is right.

Using span for displaying the change on test.

**HTML :**

```
<span id="title"></span>
```

**JS :**

```
var fieldA = 'Yes';
var fieldB = 'No';
var fieldC = 'No';

if (fieldA == "Yes" || fieldB == "Yes" || fieldC == "Yes")
    document.getElementById('title').innerHTML ="TITLE";
else  
    document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = "";
```